# Why rewrite directive causes "301 Moved Permanently" with Nginx?

Tags: redirect, nginx, webserver, url-rewriting, security

Below is a much simplified version of what I have in the configuration file of a server run by Nginx 1.2.5, yet it causes `301 Moved Permanently` with `Location: http://example.com/phpmyadmin/` before serving data, which is not what I expected from the default behavior of the `rewrite` directive.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    location /pma {
        rewrite ^ /phpmyadmin;
    }
    location /phpmyadmin {
        root /var/www;
        index Documentation.html;
    }
}
```

When I go to `http://example.com/pma` in a browser, the data is served but the URL in the address bar changes to `http://example.com/phpmyadmin/` while it was supposed to stay `http://example.com/pma`.

How do I avoid Nginx sending `301 Moved Permanently` so that it doesn't expose the actual directory structure on my server?

Answer (score 0):

Try alias:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    location /pma {
        alias /phpmyadmin;
    }
    location /phpmyadmin {
        root /var/www;
        index Documentation.html;
}
```

Comment: But I want a redirect, only an __internal__ redirect that doesn't need 301 to be sent along with the info on the real location of the served data. And again, the example is highly simplified and rewritten, the config makes perfect sense in its original form. And the question is more about why would `rewrite` lead to a `301`. This is not documented, not on the official page of the rewrite module, at least.

Comment: Tried. Same thing. Nginx sends a `301` and the URL is changed to `http://example.com/phpmyadmin/` in the browser while it was supposed to stay `http://example.com/pma`.

Comment: Did you remove the rewrite in favor of the alias?

Comment: Why would I remove rewrite when I need it to change URIs in a specific way?

Comment: in this case alias is a replacement for rewrite given your desired outcome.

Comment: If you have any code on you mind that could work, why not show it?

Comment: In regard to your code, it doesn't even get into `location /phpmyadmin` block. Checked it by placing `return 503;` at the beginning of `location /phpmyadmin` block, never got a 503. (And your code is missing one `}`).

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to use alias instead of rewrite. Rewrite creates a "new" URL, so it makes a redirect

```
server {
    listen 80;
    location /pma {
        alias  /var/www/phpmyadmin;
        index Documentation.html;
    }
    location /phpmyadmin {
        root /var/www;
        index Documentation.html;
    }
}
```